# File could not be found error downloading file in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, excel, internet-explorer

I'm having problems when trying to use the Open option in Internet Explorer when serving an excel document from an ASP.NET web app.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename.Replace(",", "") + ".xls");
Response.Charset = String.Empty;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
using(HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    gridView.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
}

Response.End();
```

I didn't write the code but what I have noticed is that if the filename length is <= 177 then it works. Anything over >= 118 I receive a file could not be found error. I've checked the the 118th character is a 0 so doesn't appear to be anything to do with this.

Any ideas what might be causing this as it seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: does your file name contain any spaces? I remember I had an issue like that before

Comment: @AmrElGarhy It does yes

Comment: is it possible to remove spaces and give it a try?

Comment: @AmrElGarhy Will do now. I'll let you know the outcome. Thanks

Comment: @AmrElGarhy That didn't work. The open button is completely unresponsive. When I click Save it will open the file. If I reduce the name of the file the Open button starts working. Very peculiar...

Comment: also make sure it has no char of these: (~, #, %, &, *, {}, \, :, <>, /, +, |, “)

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the reason:  http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_892.aspx

> Although the NTFS or FAT32 file systems can support filenames up to
>   255 characters, it isn't possible to use a file input to upload a file
>   with a name that long. This is due to the way that IE inserts the
>   chosen file into the form field.
>   When you browse to a file and select it using the File input, **IE
>   inserts the full file path. IE also limits you to 255 characters**, but
>   counts the file path against that limit. This means that if you had a
>   path with a length of 55 characters, the maximum length of the file
>   name that you could choose to upload would be 200 characters.

also this may be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/153400/20126

> However, there is still a limitation (apparently IE-only) on the
>   byte-length of the file name (a bug, I assume). So even if the file
>   name is made of only single-byte characters, the beginning of the file
>   name is truncated. The limitation is around 160 bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the top one as I'm not inserting the filename into a form element..

Comment: Also the max bytes being 160.. I seem to be able to successfully download and open a file with a filename larger than 160 bytes when calculating using string.Length * sizeof(char)

Comment: while debugging  your code, what is the filename length?

Comment: It is 178 characters. If I truncate at 117 it works. 118 it stops working.

Comment: that's not including .xls